# Is it possible to get python bytecode without using co_code?

Tags: python

I posted this a while back on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12513901/is-it-possible-to-get-python-bytecode-without-using-co-code) (too old to migrate though).

Say I am in the python interpreter and define a function as follows:

```
def h(a):
  return a
```

If I want to look at the bytecode (not a disassembly using dis), I can typically use `h.func_code.co_code`. Is there any other way to look at the bytecode? This particular application was packaged with a custom python interpreter (using py2exe probably) which removed access to co_code. I can't just look at the pyc file as they are encrypted.

For example, in the interpreter, if I just type `h` without making it a function call, I get the address of the function. Can I use that address to get the bytecode? Is there some other way?

P.S. My original goal in doing this at the time was to use pyREtic (which calls co_code) to decompile. Since it called co_code, it would fail to work. I figured out one way to do it which I will post as an answer eventually. Wanted to see what others have done or come up with.

Comment: Don't have access to a computer right now, but have you tried digging into the python source code to see what co_code does?

Comment: yeah, co_code is just a buffer that stores the bytecode of the given function.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, just a small reminder about "what is `co_code`".

In Python, every element of the language (functions, methods, classes, ...) is defined and stored in an object. The `co_code` is one of the fields attached to the class used to represent a function or a method.  Lets practice a bit with Python 2.7.

```
$> python2.7
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar  4 2013, 14:57:34) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     print('Hello World!')
... 
>>> dir(foo.__code__)

['__class__', '__cmp__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', 
 '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', 
 '__new__',  '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', 
 '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'co_argcount', 'co_cellvars', 'co_code', 'co_consts', 
 'co_filename', 'co_firstlineno', 'co_flags', 'co_freevars', 'co_lnotab', 'co_name', 
 'co_names', 'co_nlocals', 'co_stacksize', 'co_varnames']
>>> foo.__code__.co_code
'd\x01\x00GHd\x00\x00S'
```

So, you can see that the `co_code` field contain the compiled bytecode of the function we just defined previously. In fact, it seems that `co_code` is just a buffer to store the compiled bytecode in a lazy manner. It is compiled only when it is accessed for the first time.

Assuming this, the `co_code` is just a unified helper to access the bytecode which might be stored in several forms. One form are the `*.pyc` files which are storing the compiled Python bytecode of a whole file. Another form is just the on-the-fly compilation of the function/method.

Nevertheless, there is a way to access directly the function/method definition and, thus, to the bytecode. The point is to intercept the Python process with `gdb` and analyze it. A few tutorials exists in the web about this (see [here](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Low-level-Python-debugging-with-GDB), [here](http://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html), [here](http://www.jmcneil.net/2012/04/debugging-your-python-with-gdb-ftw/) or [here](http://chrismiles.livejournal.com/20226.html)). But, here is a quick example (you need to install the `python-gdb` package first):

```
$> python2.7-dbg
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar  4 2013, 14:27:19) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     print('Hello World!')
... 
[40809 refs]
>>> foo
<function foo at 0x1a5e1b0>
[40811 refs]
>>> foo.__code__.co_code
'd\x01\x00GHd\x00\x00S'
[40811 refs]
>>> 
[1]+  Stopped                 python2.7-dbg
```

Then, you need to get the PID of the Python process and attach `gdb` on it.

```
$ gdb -p 5164
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian
...
Attaching to process 5164
Program received signal SIGTSTP, Stopped (user).
Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7-dbg...done.
Reading symbols from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.13.so...done.
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".done.
...
(gdb) print *(PyFunctionObject*)0x1a5e1b0
$1 = {_ob_next = 0x187aca0, _ob_prev = 0x189dd08, ob_refcnt = 2, 
      ob_type = 0x87ce00, func_code = <code at remote 0x187aca0>, 
      func_globals = {'__builtins__': <module at remote 0x7f5ebcb5e470>,
      '__name__': '__main__', 'foo': <function at remote 0x1a5e1b0>, '__doc__': None, 
      '__package__': None}, func_defaults = 0x0, func_closure = 0x0, func_doc = None, 
      func_name = 'foo', func_dict = 0x0, func_weakreflist = 0x0, 
      func_module = '__main__'}
(gdb) print  (*(PyFunctionObject*)0x1a5e1b0)->func_name
$2 = 'foo'
(gdb) print (*(PyCodeObject*)0x187aca0)
$3 = {_ob_next = 0x18983a8, _ob_prev = 0x1a5e1b0, ob_refcnt = 1, ob_type = 0x872680, 
      co_argcount = 0, co_nlocals = 0, co_stacksize = 1, co_flags = 67,
      co_code = 'd\x01\x00GHd\x00\x00S', co_consts = (None, 'Hello World!'),
      co_names = (), co_varnames = (), co_freevars = (), co_cellvars = (),
      co_filename = '<stdin>', co_name = 'foo', co_firstlineno = 1,
      co_lnotab = '\x00\x01', co_zombieframe = 0x0, co_weakreflist = 0x0}
(gdb) print (*(PyCodeObject*)0x187aca0)->co_code
$4 = 'd\x01\x00GHd\x00\x00S'
```

So, here is the way to access directly the bytecode, given the address of the function.

Just to try to  be complete, the best documentation I found on Python bytecode (and how to access it), is the Python code itself and especially the `inspect` module ([2.7](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/inspect.py), [3.2](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/inspect.py)). Try to look at it, it is quite instructive.

Another help you can use is the [`dis` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html) that provide a disassembler for the Python bytecode. Here is an example of what can do this disassembler.

```
$> python2.7
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar  4 2013, 14:57:34) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def foo():
...     print("Hello World!")
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello World!')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              5 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              8 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: That's pretty cool! I'm not 100% sure this would have worked in the particular project I was working on as it had a custom python interpreter that I probably couldn't install the gdb bindings for. Still a great technique nonetheless. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

perror's answer I think is the correct way to do it. I wanted to post the way I ended up doing this for other's sake just in case the issue I mentioned in my comment to perror's answer is correct. I don't have all my notes with me right now and will update if necessary.

Basically I ran the program in gdb, set a break point in PyObject_New (or possibly PyObject_Init). I set the break point near the end of the function so that the object would be created. From there I was able to look into the object in memory to extract the byte code.

To get this info back to pyREtic, I dumped function names and bytecode to a file from within GDB, modified pyREtic so that instead of calling co_code to get the bytecode, it would extract it from the file.

Like I said, it has been a while now (the stackoverflow question was from Sept 2012). I'll look back over my notes and fill in the details.