# How to compile c, cpp and python code as "Released/Final" version?

Tags: python, c, c++, compilers, software-security

I want to know if there are ways to compile C, C++ and Python code in order to not be able to reverse engineering it over Linux or not?

I have heard there are some ways over Windows to do it, but I am working on Linux.

I want to compile my code securely, as released or final version.

**UPDATE**

At least I want to make it hard for usual users to disassemble,

I am using GCC for C and C++, also I would be thankful if you introduce me best compiler for Python.

Comment: Bruce Schneier's column today linked to an article about research in this field: http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/451.pdf The paper will probably not tell you how to solve this, but it will give you a good idea of just how much research there is into your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot prevent reverse engineering. You can make it more or less harder but you cannot prevent it. No.

**Update**

Ok, as the author updated it with a more clearer question... this is what one can do:

1. Strip symbols from the binaries. At the very least.
2. Obfuscate the code. This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111808/c-c-compiler-generating-obfuscated-code.
3. Pack or protect the binary. I know no good available protector for Linux, sorry.

As for the Python code... If you're lucky enough, you can use [Shedskin](https://code.google.com/p/shedskin/) to compile to native code and then apply the same techniques discussed before. If not, you may give a try to Cython instead of Python. Also, there is a question [here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/1943/what-are-the-techniques-and-tools-to-obfuscate-python-programs) about obfuscating Python code.

PS: Anyway, in my opinion, code protection is overrated. You cannot prevent a decided person or group from reverse engineering a piece of software and, sometimes, it's a lose of time and money.

Comment: Ok ..that's exactly what I want..How is it possible with compiler? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

As for C compiler (gcc), first make sure you do not make a mistake of compiling it with `-g` option (adds symbols for debugging, basically whole source code).

> -g  Produce debugging information in the operating system's native format

Secondly, try with `-s` option:

> -s  Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.

Without function names is would be harder to reverse engineer it. Take a look at `man strip`. I haven't tried it, but something like

> strip --strip-debug objfile

or:

> strip --strip-unneeded objfile

on your object files could be useful.

Turn on as much optimisation as you can `-O3`. It is really hard to read an optimized assembly, making it another impediment. There is really no good way of preventing disassembly and reverse-engineering, but it makes it harder.

As for Python, it is absolutely OK to ship only `.pyc` bytecode files. It is compiled version of source code for Python Virtual Machine. [How do I create a .pyc file?](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/how-do-i-create-a-pyc-file.htm). Try this one, maybe it is what you need. User can run bytecode file using `python` just as easily as a source code file.

Lastly, try to google for code obfuscation. It makes no sense to obfuscate C++ code, but maybe someone knows if code obfuscation is a good strategy for Python.